# mySQL Syntax for INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am trying to insert a faculty with the column shortcut if it does not exist. Yes i know, this should be easy...

So that's my code:
(I use MySQL 5.6.27)

```
INSERT INTO faculties(shortcut) SELECT 'BWI-M' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT shortcut FROM faculties WHERE shortcut = 'BWI-M');
```

And a variation:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO faculties(shortcut)
    VALUES('BWI-')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627
     RAISERROR etc
END CATCH;
```

Both throw a syntax error. I think i am really stupid, i copied the query from the docs but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `FROM` clause in your query. It should be

```
INSERT INTO faculties(shortcut) 
SELECT 'BWI-M' FROM some_table  
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM faculties WHERE shortcut = 'BWI-M');
```

(OR) you can use `dual` table like

```
INSERT INTO faculties(shortcut) 
SELECT 'BWI-M' FROM dual ....
```

Though don't see any purpose of that `WHERE NOT EXISTS` condition. You can probably just say

```
INSERT INTO faculties(shortcut) VALUES('BWI-M')
```

Comment: If that table has multiple rows, the OP would get multiple entries; they should probably select from [DUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: @Uueerdo, right. Edited answer. Thanks for pointing the same.